# Solar tracking using a helicopter blade control

Tags: control-system, servo, assembly, solar-energy, mechanical-assembly

I've been trying to build a dual-axis solar tracker but the ones I saw needed linear actuators.

I'm thinking how about using  SG100 servos with the concept of blade control in helicopters to build the tracker. Like the one [from this YouTube.](https://youtu.be/Kd1yLZen33I)

The advantage is that it's cheaper since with this approach it reduces the cost by 33%.

Can someone advise/guide me on the same?

Comment: Best one I saw involved a spring and a bucket. The bucket was slowly filled with water which as it got heavier pulled the panels around to follow the sun. Tap opened and spring pulls panels back to start.

Comment: These RC motors probably draw current all the time making them pretty inefficient when they are not moving. You only need to give the panels a small nudge once in a while. Im not sure how they behave when you turn them on so its unclear if you can turn them on, move, off, etc.

Answer (score 1):

TL/DR : Don't bother.

For a tiny tracker on a tiny panel, this might work. While the RC servo isn't moving, its current consumption will fall to a few mA.

But make sure your wind/snow/etc loading calculations are right before you let it loose on a real panel : the tiny travel of the servo will be swamped by the leverage of the real thing. In contrast, linear actuators simply scale to any travel you want; just buy a longer leadscrew (e.g. allthread for a simple DIY one)

(Also, regardless of linear axis or other, the heli control is more like what the astronomers would call altazimuth mounting; if you use an equatorial mount, you only need one axis control daily, move the other one about once a week or month).